# How to use click event for label or textblock in wpf c# visual studio?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am working on desktop application i got suggestion to use wpf instead winforms. I want to go to another form/window when i click my label but i cant find click event for label and textblock? also can anyone tell me what is left mouse up event used for?

Comment: also i know how to go from mainwindow to window i.e by creating object, how can i go from window to mainwindow it is giving e error when i am creating object in both forms/windows.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> also can anyone tell me what is left mouse up event used for?

It can for example be used to handle the click of a `TextBlock` like you want:

```
<TextBlock Text="..." MouseLeftButtonUp="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonUp" />
```

This event occurs when the left mouse button is released while the mouse pointer is over this element as stated in the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttonup(v=vs.110).aspx

You could also handle the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttondown(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use PreviewMouseDown Event on TextBlock.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" PreviewMouseDown="TextBlock_Clicked"/>
```